# Realtek RTL8188CUs

Tags: kernel, compiling

I am trying to use an airlink wifi dongle with RTL8188CUs chip.

It has not been going very well. I found a link to a driver installer
Download  rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb   1.0 MB

When I run this installer I get the error:

```
(Reading database ... 305433 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms 1.6 (using .../rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb) ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.6
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking replacement rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms ...
Setting up rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms (1.6) ...
Loading new rtl8192cu-tjp-1.6 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.11.0-19-generic
Building for architecture i386
Building initial module for 3.11.0-19-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-19-generic (i386)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

The make log is this:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8192cu-tjp-1.6 for kernel 3.11.0-19-generic (i386)
Fri Apr  4 20:25:18 CDT 2014
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: gcc: command not found
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc: command not found
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic'
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:98: stack protector enabled but no compiler support
make: gcc: Command not found
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 127
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8192cu-tjp/1.6/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic'
```

If anyone understands any of this please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the build-essential package and try again.  You are missing the compiler.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```